# Using a Service Account for Admin API with OAuth2 library in Google Apps Script to Add A User to a Google Group

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, service-accounts

---

### EDIT:

*The URL needs to be `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{groupKey}/members` and not `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{groupKey}/members/insert` (without the `insert`, even though  it's the `insert` method)*

---

I am trying to build a script with Google Apps Script that would be able to add users to a Google Group with a service account. Now, using the `AdminDirectory` service is straightforward, so this code works:

```js
const addUser = email => {
  const member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(
    { email, role: 'MEMBER' },
    'test-group@domain.com'
  );
};
```

However this service requires super-user privileges. Hence my decision was to use a service account.

I created the service account and went through [the whole checklist](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation):

1. I generated the JSON key
2. Enabled domain-wide delegation
3. In the Admin Console > Security > API Controls > Domain-wide Delegation I added the following scopes:

   - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
   - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
   - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member
4. Then I built this solution that uses the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2):

```js
const addUserWithServiceAccount = email => {
  const serviceAccount = {
    type: 'service_account',
    project_id: 'my-tools-324016',
    private_key_id: '021623b...',
    private_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
    client_email: 'SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL',
    client_id: '1059879019...',
    auth_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    token_uri: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
    client_x509_cert_url:
      'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/...',
  };

  const _getAdminService = serviceAccount => {
    return OAuth2.createService('admin-sdk-test')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      .setPrivateKey(serviceAccount.private_key)
      .setIssuer(serviceAccount.client_email)
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      .setLock(LockService.getUserLock())
      .setScope([
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
      ]);
  };

  const _executeWithAuth2 = (groupKey, email) => {
    console.log('_executeWithAuth2()');
    const adminService = _getAdminService(serviceAccount);
    if (!adminService.hasAccess()) {
      Logger.log('ERROR n' + adminService.getLastError());
      return;
    }

    const url = `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/${groupKey}/members/insert?memberKey=${email}`;

    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${adminService.getAccessToken()}`,
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    const options = {
      method: 'put',
      headers,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      payload: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        role: 'MEMBER',
        kind: 'admin#directory#member',
        type: 'USER',
      }),
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };

    console.log(`fetch(${url}, ${JSON.stringify(options, null, 2)})`);

    const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  };

  return _executeWithAuth2('test-group@domain', email);
};
```

Now when I run it, I get the following error in response:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And when I switch `PUT` to `POST` I get:

> The requested URL `/admin/directory/v1/groups/test-group@domain.com/members/insert?memberKey=user@domain.com` was not found on this server.

However this approach with the Service Account [works very well with BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67036798/google-sheets-addon-appscript-bigquery-integration-via-service-account). And even though I wasn't able to find an Admin Directory-specific solution, I was expecting it to work in the same way.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A service account does not have super-user privileges neither

This is why you are getting an `Not Authorized` error.

- The service account needs to [impersonate](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) the super-user with the respective privelleges.
- For this, in addition to enabling domain-wide delegation, you need to specify the impersonated user programmatically by seetting him as [subject](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) with `.setSubject("EMAIL OF SUPER USER")`.

Sample:

```js
const _getAdminService = serviceAccount => {
    return OAuth2.createService('admin-sdk-test')
      .setSubject("EMAIL OF SUPER USER")
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      .setPrivateKey(serviceAccount.private_key)
      .setIssuer(serviceAccount.client_email)
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      .setLock(LockService.getUserLock())
      .setScope([
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
      ]);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution! This got me to move on, but I'm now getting a different error: **Resource Not Found: memberKey**. Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: This is a different question, but in short: `memberKey` should go into the resource body, not into the URL. If you expand the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/insert?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22groupKey%22%3A%22testGroup%40yourdomain.com%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22email%22%3A%22testUser%40yourdomain.com%22%7D%7D), you can see how the request is meant to be structured for cURL, HTTP and Javascript.

Comment: I might be a a little slow, but I don't see any `memberKey` in you the link you provided. The only member info they have their is their email, and I've already got that.

Comment: Funnily enough I got the cUrl script to work, even though it doesn't force impersonisation

Comment: And what I also don't get why `POST` requests return a `404` error, whereas I think we can agree the cUrl request is a `POST` request, yet it works no problem.

Comment: Turns out the reason is a lot simpler, the URL needs to be `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{groupKey}/members` and not `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{groupKey}/members/insert`. I'll accept your answer though as you've been super helpful and gave great some tips!